# android.permission.INTERNET

Tags: java, android, permissions

Столкнулся со следующей проблемой:
необходимо спарсить данные из JSON файла, находящегося по определенной ссылке. Для этого использую классы org.json.*. Для доступа к интернет-соединению в AndroidManifest указываю следующее:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Но при запуске приложения на Android 6 у меня вылетает следующее исключение:

> Permission denied (missing INTERNET permission?)

Прочитал в доках Android про Runtime Permissions и понял, что, возможно, проблема кроется в том, что android.permission.INTERNET является опасным разрешением и придется дописывать пару методов для запроса разрешения во время исполнения программы.
Но погуглив наткнулся на такую [статью с хабра](https://habrahabr.ru/post/278945/), где указывается, что доступ к интернету не является опасным.
Так в чем же тогда проблема?

upd: файл AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="ru.cargomart.cargomart" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Возможно вы не там прописали разрешения? Покажите манифест целиком

Comment: К сожалению, AndroidManifest превышает количество допустимых символов в комментарии. Разрешения прописал между тегами <manifest...> и <application...>

Comment: Дополнять вопрос лучше через правку вопроса, не в комментариях

Comment: А какие у Вас значения `compileSdkVersion` и `targetSdkVersion`?

Comment: @post_zeew, 23 стоит. Попробовал Ваше решение, тоже ничего не вышло

Comment: @AndreiO., То есть если выставить  `targetSdkVersion 22`, то происходит та же ошибка?

Comment: @post_zeew, да. А не может быть все таки это из-за того, что я не юзаю runtime permission?

Comment: @AndreiO., По-умолчанию – нет. Так как `android.permission.INTERNET` не относится к `Dangerous permissions`, следовательно, оно относится к `Normal permissions`, для которых `Normal permissions do not directly risk the user's privacy. If your app lists a normal permission in its manifest, the system grants the permission automatically.`.

Comment: Но при использовании кастомных прошивок может быть все что угодно, так что попробуйте все-таки запросить это разрешение у пользователя. У вас, случайно, не кастом? Какое вообще устройство?

Comment: @post_zeew, нет, не катом. Запускал на Nexus 5 и BQ Strike

Comment: @AndreiO., Тогда странно, ибо нерутованный Nexus – это эталонный девайс.

Answer (score 1):

Хмм... а сама среда Android Studio, sdk, build tools - все свежее?
Вот тут признавали похожую проблему 3 года назад, https://www.parse.com/questions/android-sdk-parseasynctask-runtimeexception, но обещали пофиксить в следующих версиях sdk. Может, рецидив. Попробуй написать им. И, кстати, было бы неплохо увидеть кусок кода, который у тебя связан с интернет-соединением, хоть и сомневаюсь, что мы оттуда что-то  полезное узнаем, и твой build.gradle...